# Encrypt web.config Error No mapping between account name and security IDs was done

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to encryp web.confif using RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.
Everything works fine on my machine which is Windows XP. I know I am supposed to use "ASPNET" in following command for XP. My test server is WIndows server 2007 and following command gives me an error. "No mapping between account name and security IDs was done." I know ASPNET is not the default application pool on the server. What command should I use on the server?

aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "ASPNET"
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the answer. Command should be this on the windows server.

It shoud be aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"